# About to replace windows with Ubuntu 11.10. Will this cause any problems?

Tags: ubuntu, windows, wubi

I have Ubuntu installed on a (originally just Windows) machine using wubi. What are the chances of going something horribly wrong if I were to:

1. create a new partition
2. Install Ubuntu 11.10 on it using a CD
3. format the partitions with Windows and wubi on them.

Will this successfully make Ubuntu 11.10 as my main OS?

In case anyone is wondering why I want to do so: simply because I never use windows and it's just sitting there idle, taking up space.

Comment: There are migration scripts available on the ubuntu wiki that work.

Comment: BACKUP. I know it is a pain, but do it.

Comment: Never used migration scripts before. My original plan was to back up all data, and [transfer installed packages](http://eggsonbread.com/2010/01/28/move-ubuntu-to-another-computer-in-3-simple-steps/) to my new partition. Will this work as well? Or do you think migration scripts would work the best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have things on the Ubuntu installation that you want to access in the future, then I would avoid Rory Alsop's suggestion; otherwise, his is the easiest way if you don't mind losing everything you have.

One nice thing about Linux is that the configurations, preferences, etc, are all in files that can be copied, unlike windows with its registry.  So, if you are at all technically inclined (not necessarily a guru), you could use a live Linux CD, such as the Ubuntu CD, run gparted, and create a partition big enough for any data you may want to keep. If you have any Windows data you want to save, this would be a good time to do it while using the live CD.

Then, run the WUBI install, and copy the data, or your home directory, to the new partition, making sure to get the hidden files.

Once you do that, you can reformat the Windows Partition and install Ubuntu there (all from the installation program).  Once you get everything the way you want, you can run gparted to delete the smaller partition, and grow the main partition to full size.

Comment: hang on, I can copy data _during_ WUBI install? How do I go about doing that?

or did you mean logging in to the WUBI partition, and copy the data over to the new partition?

Comment: Sorry, no, I meant run the WUBI installation, not install.  So while running it, you can copy data over to the new partition, or to a backup of some sort.

Comment: So it all went smooth until I tried migrating/moving my installed packages. so I had to overwrite pre-existing partitions and install a clean Ubuntu on a single partition.

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Well, I'm not totally sure what you did, but I'm glad it seemed to work out.  There are usually a number of ways to accomplish things in Linux once you understand a few basics.  You probably learned some of those during this experience, and soon it will not seem hard. Unfortunately, you will probably learn a few things the hard way along your journey. :)  But if you avoid things like WUBI, it will be much easier.

Answer (score 1):

If you do want to remove windows, I would suggest a simpler, and far less risky way:

- back up everything you want to keep
- buy or make an Ubuntu install CD
- run the install CD
- when given the options, choose 'use full hard disk' for your install, and just go with all the defaults

this will remove the windows partition anyway and set up partitions for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no problems, just ensure that you have a backup of all your relevant data.